# contenteditable dynamic on off when selection

Tags: firefox, cross-browser, contenteditable

I have a website like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="block">
<span id="c1" class="chunk">first </span>
<span id="c2" class="chunk">second </span>
<span id="c3" class="chunk">third </span>
</div>

<script>

    var my = {
        mousedown: function(event) {
            $('.chunk').each(function() {
                this.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'false');
            });
        },
        mouseup: function(event) {
            $('.chunk').each(function() {
                this.setAttribute('contenteditable', 'true');
            });
        }
    };

    $('.chunk')
    .on('mousedown', my.mousedown)
    .on('mouseup', my.mouseup)
    ;

    my.mouseup(null);

</script>

</body>

</html>
```

The desired outcome is like in chrome:

when I click the chunk, I can write text and I see a caret (cursor)
and when I select the contenteditable gets disabled for the time of selection

BUT IN FIREFOX:

I can not type anymore inside the contenteditable
because the onmousedown disables the contenteditable in time of onclick (I think)

CAN U HELP WITH FIX? I'm looking for cross-browser solution to this.
PLEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer appeared to be simpler thant I thought. The main containing parent has to have contenteditable=true, after this, everything worked in every browser like it should. And now the mousemove and mousedown simulating selectstart also work like they should (another feature of this project), so remember when having similar problem: **just create one contenteditable main container and you will not have problems with selections**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script src="jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>

<div id="block" contenteditable="true">
<span id="c1" class="chunk">first </span>
<span id="c2" class="chunk">second </span>
<span id="c3" class="chunk">third </span>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```